# Why do I not seem to have hidraw options on my system, and how can I fix my usb devices?

Tags: linux, usb, udev

Starting today, I noticed a few problems with my system. USB devices, including the internal ones such as microphones, don't seem to be working at all. I first noticed when my keyboard and mouse weren't responding - however, checking `dmesg`, both the logitech unifying receiver and my external mics usb connections were being recognized.

Thinking at first that the receiver may have simply stopped recognizing the input devices, I figured I'd resync them and I'd be good to go - except, that when I went to reference the needed hidraw device, I didn't have any. There is no `/dev/hidraw`, no `/sys/class/hidraw`, no anything it seems. (except a hidraw header under `/usr/include` and some hidraw files under `/usr/src`)

So that *seems* to be at least part of the problem - udev seems to be failing to do its job somewhere. But I've got no idea where to go next.

Here's relevant bits that might be useful:
From dmesg:

```
[  178.045682] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 201203
[  970.636450] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[  970.731693] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
[  970.731698] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  970.731701] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB Receiver
[  970.731704] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
```

From lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

From the udev monitor (udevadm monitor):

```
KERNEL[1111.431718] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2 (usb)
KERNEL[1111.432374] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[1111.432430] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[1111.432495] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [1111.438072] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [1111.441642] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1111.442308] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1111.442924] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.2 (usb)
```

Answer (score 0):

This same thing happened to me.
I had to compile the kernel to get it to work.
Before compiling the kernel you have to make sure you have raw HID enabled.

```
sudo make menuconfig

Device Drivers --->
  HID Support --->
    /dev/hidraw raw HID device support
```

If you don't know how to compile the kernel, you can do a quick google search. This is the one I used (Ubuntu): [Howto compile Linux kernel 3.8 / 3.x in Ubuntu 13.04 12.10 12.04](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/08/how-to-compile-and-install-linux-kernel-3-0-in-ubuntu-11-04-10-10-and-10-04/)